# How to bind a templateUrl to an element

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind

I want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-templateUrl="path/to/{{item.templateName}}.html" id="item.id"></div>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to embed templates into elements.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. I only looked for the wrong expression.